# Difference between geometry() and $geometry in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry

What is the difference between `geometry()` and `$geometry` in QGIS?

I didn't find any examples of using this function.

[image: geometry and $geometry]

Particularly I'm interested in `geometry()`, in what cases it is helpful?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Right next to the list of functions your screenshot is of, should be the currently selected function's documentation. For me, with QGIS 2.18.12 those read:

**`$geometry`** *Returns the geometry of the current feature. Can be used for processing with other functions.*

**`geometry()`** *Returns a feature's geometry.*

This is like the different of a method versus a function in object-oriented programming. `$geometry` is *this*/*self*'s geometry. You can think of it more like an attribute or property maybe.

`geometry()` on the other hand requires/allows you to pass a feature to it and it will *return* the corresponding geometry. As the documentation shows, you can use this to get the geometry from an attribute-based feature selection:

```
geometry(
  get_feature(layer, attributeField, value)
)
```

What else you can do with it is just limited by your creativity and the sources for *features* to pass to it. :)

Comment: So, how I can use it when trying to transform separate points that forms line ( (make_line(   make_point(  "xlbl" -1000, "ylbl" ), 
make_point(( "xlbl"+ length( ( "time" ))*3000+7000 ) , "ylbl" ),) ... etc
I mean that I want to transform every point of line, based on coordinates in attribute table values

Comment: I suppose I have to represent every point of my line (from make_point func) as geometry, then transform it, so far as the whole constructed geometry make_line transforms wrong https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253002/rotate-geometry-generator-marker-line-depending-on-map-projection-qgis

Comment: Sure thing. This sounds like using the wrong tool though, have you tried the points2one plugin or some other processing?

Comment: No, this is a style of the layer, I can't use any plugins in layer properties. I try to solve my problem by dint of qgis built-in functions

Comment: The property comparison sounds good but the OO comparison is a bit weak, `$geometry` is rather a (const) variable, regardless if OO or not.

Answer (score 17):

`$geometry` returns the geometry of the *current* feature as in:

```
geom_to_wkt($geometry)
```

`geometry()` returns the geometry of a *specific* feature as in

```
geom_to_wkt(geometry(get_feature('my_layer', 'my_feature', feature_id)))
```

You would use the second case if you wanted, for example, to process the current feature against a specific feature:

```
intersects($geometry, geometry(get_feature(layer, attributeField, value)))
```